# Работа с БД в сервисе

Tags: android

Можно ли работать с БД в сервисе? Дело вот в чем. Есть приложение которое берет аудио файл из assets и проигрывает его. Это все происходит в активити. А Названия этих файлов хранятся в БД. Думаю перенести всю логику плеера в сервис.

Поэтому вопрос.. Можно ли в сервисе работать с БД и AssetFileDescriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, никаких ограничений на работу с sqlite и assets в сервисе нет.

Answer (score 2):

Да. С чего Вы решили, что нельзя? Все проигрыватели работают в сервисах.

Comment: Я не решил, но все-таки думаю спрошу у более опытных людей